# The Flutter build is stuck on the splash screen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

**Flutter build is stuck on the splash screen. I tried it on both a real device and the Pixel 4 Api33 emulator. Using Namal woocommerce source code available on codecanyon website and I am a beginner. I tried my best to figure out what's wrong but I failed. Asking for your help guys, please let me know if you need any other information.**

`**main.dart error log file on Pixel 4 Api33 emulator**`

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Attaching Geolocator to activity
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(10640): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterLocationService(10640): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(10640): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator(10640): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54544/-pXfnrJ83sQ=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
V/OneSignal(10640): Initializing the OneSignal Flutter SDK (3.3.2)
D/OneSignal(10640): Adding a task to the pending queue with ID: 1
D/OneSignal(10640): startPendingTasks with task queue quantity: 1
D/OneSignal(10640): Attempted to clean 6 month old IAM data, but none exists!
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal InAppMessageTracker initInfluencedTypeFromCache: OSChannelTracker{tag=iam_id, influenceType=UNATTRIBUTED, indirectIds=null, directId=null}
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal NotificationTracker initInfluencedTypeFromCache: OSChannelTracker{tag=notification_id, influenceType=UNATTRIBUTED, indirectIds=null, directId=null}
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal getUnattributedUniqueOutcomeEventsSentByChannel: null
W/OneSignal(10640): appContext set, but please call setAppId(appId) with a valid appId to complete OneSignal init!
V/OneSignal(10640): setAppId called with id: YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID changing id from: null
V/OneSignal(10640): Starting OneSignal initialization!
D/OneSignal(10640): Retrieved IAMs from DB redisplayedInAppMessages: []
V/OneSignal(10640): No class found, not setting up OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler
I/OneSignal(10640): Last Pending Task has ran, shutting down
V/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal SDK initialization delayed, waiting for remote params.
D/OneSignal(10640): Starting request to get Android parameters.
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignalRestClient: Making request to: https://api.onesignal.com/apps/YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID/android_params.js
W/SQLiteLog(10640): (28) double-quoted string literal: "notification"
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignalRestClient: Adding header if-none-match: W/"05702b137a259242f45cdd80824abb9f"
D/TrafficStats(10640): tagSocket(135) with statsTag=0x2710, statsUid=-1
V/OneSignal(10640): OneSignalRestClient: After con.getResponseCode to: https://api.onesignal.com/apps/YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID/android_params.js
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignalRestClient: GET - Using Cached response due to 304: {"awl_list":{},"receive_receipts_enable":false}
D/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal saveInfluenceParams: InfluenceParams{indirectNotificationAttributionWindow=1440, notificationLimit=10, indirectIAMAttributionWindow=1440, iamLimit=10, directEnabled=false, indirectEnabled=false, unattributedEnabled=false}
D/OneSignal(10640): reassignDelayedInitParams with appContext: androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication@7610e7d
V/OneSignal(10640): setAppId called with id: YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID changing id from: null
V/OneSignal(10640): Starting OneSignal initialization!
V/OneSignal(10640): No class found, not setting up OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler
E/OneSignal(10640): OneSignal AppId format is invalid.
E/OneSignal(10640): Example: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba'
E/OneSignal(10640): 
E/OneSignal(10640): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID
E/OneSignal(10640):     at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OSUtils.initializationChecker(OSUtils.java:118)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(OneSignal.java:841)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.setAppId(OneSignal.java:735)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.reassignDelayedInitParams(OneSignal.java:1181)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.onRemoteParamSet(OneSignal.java:889)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignal$7.complete(OneSignal.java:1122)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignalRemoteParams.processJson(OneSignalRemoteParams.java:211)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignalRemoteParams.access$100(OneSignalRemoteParams.java:12)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignalRemoteParams$1.onSuccess(OneSignalRemoteParams.java:156)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient$5.run(OneSignalRestClient.java:279)
E/OneSignal(10640):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
V/OneSignal(10640): initWithContext called with: androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication@7610e7d
V/OneSignal(10640): Starting OneSignal initialization!
V/OneSignal(10640): No class found, not setting up OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler
I/flutter (10640): --> GET https://sidemenclothing.in/wp-json/api/tc_settings/app_all_settings
I/flutter (10640): {clientid: 1234, clientsecret: sk_1234, X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, authorization: }
[log]  
<-- START PARAMS: 
null
END PARAMS -->
<-- END HTTP
I/flutter (10640): Hivedata
I/flutter (10640): Instance of 'BoxImpl<WooCartData>'
E/flutter (10640): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (10640): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter (10640): #1      _SplashScreenState.getCart (package:flutter_kundol/ui/screens/splash_screen.dart:136:28)
E/flutter (10640): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10640): 
I/flutter (10640): <-- 200 GET https://sidemenclothing.in/wp-json/api/tc_settings/app_all_settings
[log]  
<-- START RESPONSE: 
{last_tab: 1, home_style: 1, category_style: 1, banner_style: 3, card_style: 1, cancel_order_button: 0, cancel_order_hours: 1, package_name: app.beastdeals, site_url: https://sidemenclothing.in/, new_product_duration: 5, filter_max_price: 100000, update_order: 10, one_page_checkout: 1, checkout_process: yes, custom_css_for_checkout: .site-header, nav, #secondary, footer {display: none!important;}, contact_us_email: info@domain-name.com, from_email: from@domain-name.com, phone_no: +92 123 456-789, address: 228 Park avs, city: New York, state: NY, Zip: 10003, Country: USA, Latitude: 40.730610, Longitude: -73.935242, sidebar_menu_icon: 0, wish_list_page: 0, edit_profile_page: 0, shipping_address_page: 0, my_orders_page: 0, contact_us_page: 0, about_us_page: 0, bill_ship_info: 0, downloads: 0, news_page: 0, intro_page: 0, share_app: 0, rate_app: 0, setting_page: 0, notification_title: Theme Coder, notification_text: A bundle of products wating for you!, notification_duration: 0, facebook_login: 0, about_page_id: , refund_page_id: , privacy_page_id: , terms_page_id: , wpml_enabled: 0, mvf_enabled: 0, wp_point_reward: 0, wp_multi_currency: 0, delivery_tracking: 0, tracking_url: http://urltracking.com/, geo_fencing: 0, one_signal_notification: 0, one_signal_app_id: , one_signal_app_key: , privacy_page: , refund_page: , terms_page: , about_page: , currency: {name: INR, position: left}, language: {name: en_US}}
END RESPONSE -->
<-- END HTTP
E/flutter (10640): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (10640): #0      _SplashScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_kundol/ui/screens/splash_screen.dart:74:76)
E/flutter (10640): #1      _BlocListenerBaseState._subscribe.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_listener.dart:204:24)
E/flutter (10640): #2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)
E/flutter (10640): #3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (10640): #4      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (10640): #5      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (10640): #6      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (10640): #7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (10640): #8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (10640): 
D/EGL_emulation(10640): app_time_stats: avg=988.05ms min=162.14ms max=1813.96ms count=2
```

`**pubsec.yml file**`

```css
name: flutter_kundol
description: A new Flutter ecommerce application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.6 <3.0.5'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.3 # need to change InitialState implementations for above 7.3.3
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  dio: ^4.0.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
#  flutter_range_slider: "^1.5.0"
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  flutter_login_facebook: ^1.6.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  in_app_review: ^2.0.4
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.4.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  dropdown_search: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^2.0.0-mb.22
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.12
  bubble_tab_indicator: ^0.1.6
  webview_flutter: ^2.8.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  hive: ^2.2.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/langs/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/json/

  fonts:
    - family: MontserratRegular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
    - family: MontserratLight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
    - family: MontserratMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
    - family: MontserratBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
    - family: MontserratSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[image]

Comment: "OneSignal AppId format is invalid." `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID`. It is probably the issue here. Check your One Signal ID or and any other one signal config.

Comment: @AlexRintt I dont want to set up onesignal. It's a purchased source code where I edited something a little bit. I didn't edit anything to onesignal. If it's the issue of one signal then how to rectify it?

Comment: idk, seems you do not have the one signal ID, there's some ways to fix this issue: 1. you create an signal account and get ID and configure your one signal properly. 2. remove one signal sdk and usages from your code. All of it _is just speculation_ this seems to be a set of issues, not a specific-one.